# Конект к ASA из java при помощи jdbc

Tags: jdbc, java, linux

У меня стоит Убунту, java 1.7, есть библиотека `sajdbc4.jar` при помощи которой можно конектится к БД.
Проблема в том, что когда я объявляю

```
Class.forName("sybase.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver");
```

компилятор ругался на отсутствие библиотеки `libdbjdbc12.so`
Я посмотрел `java.library.path` и в одну из папок, в которой было пусто, сгрузил все библиотеки, которые были в комплекте с дистрибутивом `sybase`, теперь он ругается по другому:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/java/packages/lib/i386/libdbjdbc12.so.1: libdbtasks12_r.so: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

хотя эта библиотека лежит рядом с `libdbjdbc12.so.1`

Что нужно сделать, чтобы она увидела все нужные ему библиотеки?

ЗЫ: это не веб проект

**UPD1** : есть же и другие драйвера :), взял попробовать их(jtds, jconn4)... в итоге уперся в неправильный логин/пароль, то есть до сервера я достучался и драйвер заработал. Сервер у меня на cp1251. а соединение идет с убунту, а значит UTF8.

```
//для jconn4
        Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance() );
        String userUTF8="db",pswdUTF8="sql",dburlUTF8 = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.1.1:5344/testdb";
        String userCP1251 = new String(userUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Cp1251");
        String pswdCP1251 = new String(pswdUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Cp1251");
        String dburlCP1251 = new String(dburlUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Cp1251");
        //System.out.println(dburlCP1251+" "+userCP1251+" "+pswdCP1251);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dburlCP1251, userCP1251 , pswdCP1251);

//для jtds
        Class.forName( "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" ).newInstance() );
        String userUTF8="db",pswdUTF8="sql",dburlUTF8 = "jdbc:jtds:sybase://192.168.1.1:5344/testdb";
        String userCP1251 = new String(userUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Cp1251");
        String pswdCP1251 = new String(pswdUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Cp1251");
        String dburlCP1251 = new String(dburlUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Cp1251");
        //System.out.println(dburlCP1251+" "+userCP1251+" "+pswdCP1251);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dburlCP1251, userCP1251 , pswdCP1251);
```

в итоге такие вот ошибки:

```
//для jconn4
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: JZ00L: Login failed.  Examine the SQLWarnings chained to this exception for the reason(s).
//для jtds
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Login failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то руки не доходили написать решение :)
Собственно поддержка sybase отписала следущее :

- sybase не поддерживает коннект с jtds, так что пытаться незачем :(
- строка коннекта из jconn4 должна выглядеть так :`"jdbc:sybase:Tds:localhost:2638?ServiceName=DatabaseName"`

Для себя я еще выяснил что танцы с кодировками ни к чему.
В моем случае описанном выше должно быть так :

```
//для jconn4
        Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
        String user="db",pswd="sql",dburl="jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.1.1:5344/?ServiceName=testdb";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, pswd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, что правильно понял, но предположу, что если это Web проект, то засунь jar в папку с проектом.

Comment: Пока что это просто скрипт и дальше загрузки драйвера для работы с БД он не идет.